# Program cannot handle unique words

Tags: python

I have ran into a logic error that I cannot solve and would like some assistance towards it.
Here's my code

```
Mysentence = MySentence 
print(Mysentence)
MysentenceList = Mysentence.split()
List = []

for k in MysentenceList:
    position = MysentenceList.index(k)
    position = position + 1
    position = str(position)
    List.append(position)
```

Basically cannot handle unique words

Comment: So there's no error here - `I` is the third word in the sentence. Why would you want to replace `I` with `2`? Do you mean it's the second *unique* word?

Comment: Yes yes that what im trying to say! Sorry for not clearly stating what this is meant to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign each word a "unique id", you'd have to manage this in another data structure. Another list would do the trick:

```
UniqueWords = []
for k in ThesentenceList:
    if k in UniqueWords:
        position = UniqueWords.index(k)
    else:
        position = len(UniqueWords)
        UniqueWords.append(k)
    position = position + 1
    position = str(position)
    TheList.append(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list after splitting is `["Hello", "Hello", "I", "Hello"]` which you then use to assign the word index value.

The first instance of "Hello" is index 0, the first instance of "I" is index 2. If you want to assign a "unique word ID" counting from zero without gaps in the sequence you're going to have to change your ID assignment algorithm to manage the duplicate words.

I'd propose using something like a Python dictionary to track the unique words as you find them (it's a hash map, so avoids list iteration with "index" which is going to get pretty slow with long inputs).

Answer (score 0):

`list.index(item)` is giving you the position of first instance of `item` in `list`.  The first instance of "Hello" is in position 0, but you're adding 1 to the position, so it's going to report 1 each time.  "I" is located in position 2, so it's reporting 3.